# Cypher-Neo4j Node Single Property change to Array

Tags: properties, neo4j, cypher

Following is a Node we having in DB

```
P:Person { name:"xxx", skill:"Java" }
```

and after awhile, we would like to change the Skill to skill array, is it possible?

```
P:Person { name:"xxx", skill:["Java", "Javascript"] }
```

Which Cypher query should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I think your real problem here is not how to get an array property in a node, but how to store it. Your data model is wrong in my opinion, storign data as array in neo4j is not common, since you have relations to store multiple skills (in your example).

### How to create your data model

With your question, I can already see that you have one User, and one User can have 1..n skills.

I guess that one day (maybe tomorrow) you will need to know which users are able to use Java, C++, PHP, and every othre skills.

So, Here you can already see that every skill should have its own node.

### What is the correct model in this case?

I think that, still with only what you said in question, you should have something like this:

```
(:Person{name:"Foo"})-[:KNOWS]->(:Skill{name:"Bar"})
```

using such a data model, you can get every `Skill` known by a `Person` using this query:

```
MATCH (:Person{name:"Foo"})-[:KNOWS]->(skill:Skill)
RETURN skill //or skill.name if you just want the name
```

and you can also get every `Person` who knows a `Skill` using this:

```
MATCH (:Skill{name:"Bar"})<-[:KNOWS]-(person)
RETURN person //Or person.name if you just want the name
```

**Keep in mind**

- Storing array values in properties should be the last option when you are using neo4j.
- If a property can be found in multiple nodes, having the same value, you can create a node to store it, then you will be able to link it the other nodes using relations, and finding every node having the property X = Y will be easier.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, array should be the last option. Actually, the real situation I am facing is not "skill" but "time stamp" of web site visit/app open. Should I store this info in "User" node or make it independent node? Thank you

Comment: You want to store timestamp of a visit, so the logic way to do it is using something like this: `(:User)-[:VISITED{timestamp: 144XXXXXXX}]->(:WebSite)` and `(:User)-[:OPENED{timestamp: 144XXXXXXX}]->(:App)`
If you want to store an action AND its timestamp, relation properties are perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single skill value in `skill`, then just do

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE HAS (p.skill)
SET p.skill=[p.skill]
```

If there are multiple values you need to convert to an array such as `P:Person { name:"xxx", skill:"Java","JavaScript" }` then this should work:

```
MATCH (p:P)
SET p.skill= split(p.skill,",")
```